# Pressing back does not return to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have a problem with adding the fragment transactions to the back stack. I have a Main activity in which I populate my layout with a Menu Fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag_container, new MainMenuFragment()).commit();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Then, inside the MainMenuFragment, the user chooses some option which results in replacing the menu fragment with some other fragment:

```
public class MainMenuFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener{
    GridView grid;
    FragmentManager manager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_fragment, container, false);

    manager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    grid = (GridView) root.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    grid.setAdapter(new MenuTileAdapter(getActivity()));
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
    if (position == 0){
        trans.replace(R.id.frag_container, new BasicSettingsFragment());
        trans.addToBackStack(null);
        trans.commit();
    }
}
```

}

For what i understand, this should make it so that when the user presses back button on their device, they will be brought back to the menu fragment, but instead this quits the app. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try adding instead of replacing trans.add(R.id.frag_container, new BasicSettingsFragment());

Comment: Also, i just noticed when rotating the screen, that the menu fragment didn't get removed at all, just hidden. When i rotated my phone, it appeared over the `BasicSettingsFragment`. @GeorgianBenetatos adding only put the new fragment on top of the previous one.

Comment: You should post the full MainMenuFragment code, everything looks fine.

Comment: is frag_container a framelayout inside activity_main?

Comment: @GeorgianBenetatos I just updated the post with complete code. frga_container is indeed a FrameLayout that is defined within activity_main's XML file.

Comment: Your code is a mixup, you use ActionBarActivity from appcompat and not using getSupportFragmentManager() and the fragments import should be the appcompat one if you decide to use it. If not, use Activity instead of ActionBarActivity and the simple Fragment import with FragmentManager

Comment: And since you are using the activity just to show a fragment, make activity_main.xml into a framelayout that pops the fragment into it!

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But unfortunately, without extending ActionBarActivity, i can't have action bar, and i couldn't find non-support library variant of it.

Comment: Activiy has actionbar, ActionBarActivity is support for api level 2, you got fooled by the name . You will see there is another sort of support for activities that use fragments, called FragmentActivity, most of them are deprecated.

Comment: Actually, I just tried rotating my phone again, and it still seems that the `MainMenuFragment` isn't removed on replace. When I rotate it appears over my `BasicSettingsFragment` just the way it did before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61941/discussion-between-georgian-benetatos-and-jammaster).

Comment: What devices are you targeting? Specifically, what API level? If you are targeting < API 11, then you should use ActionBarActivity. If you are targeting >= API 11, then you can simply use Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a mixup, you use ActionBarActivity from appcompat and not using getSupportFragmentManager() and the fragments import should be the appcompat one if you decide to use it. If not, use Activity instead of ActionBarActivity and the simple Fragment import with FragmentManager

Add this to your activity `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`
This will stop your activity from restarting when you rotate.
use `setRetainInstance(true)` on fragments.

Comment: You should probably encourage the OP to post a new question then.

Answer (score 5):

In your **Activity** overwrite:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And probably you need to use in every commited fragment transaction:

```
FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the MainMenuFragment to the back stack. You can try this one on your activity:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(
R.id.frag_container, new MainMenuFragment()).
addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add or replace a fragment with the `FragmentManager`, you need to manually add the old fragment to the backstack with `addToBackStack()` before calling `commit()`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. The problem is that when i use `replace`, it doesn't remove the old fragment, because when i rotate the screen, it appears on top of what was there before rotation.